# AFK command discord (JDA)

Tags: discord-jda

So, i am trying to make an afk system on my Discord Bot.
It have to put [AFK] near the nick of a user (es. [AFK] ohsavee), and if someone ping the user that is afk the bot have to say "@ohSavee is afk". I am having problems with it, can someone help me maybe sending the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A good example is using a database and storing their AFK reason. So when someone is AFK, it checks their reason in that database.

Or you could use an HashMap<Long, String> (Long = Their UserID, String = Their reason). If they are in the HashMap, you get the String by getting it from their user ID.

Comment: l m f a o
@Nimantha, this post is from 2021. This is at least 2 years ago. And you removed stuff that people always scream to me for 

Comment: Noted. The content (removed in Revision 2) on how to ask a question would be better suited as a comment under the question. The commentary on not providing code is not required in the question, though if required, or could be posted as a comment under this answer